# Save jQuery selector and function to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Save/Edit button. I would like it to do different things depending on whether it's currently a Save button or an Edit button. For clarity, I want to save the jQuery selector and function to a variable name, then call it:

```
    $('div#' + id + ' .edit').click(function(){

        var i = this;
        var state = function(st){
            if( typeof st !== 'undefined')
                $(i).html(st);
            else
                return $(i).html();
        };

        if( state() == 'Edit' ) {
            controller.edit(id);
            state('Save');
        } else {
            controller.save();
            state('Edit');
        }

    });
```

My question: is there a faster way to do this? Something like the following:

```
    $('div#' + id + ' .edit').click(function(){

        var state = $(this).html;

        if( state() == 'Edit' ) {
            controller.edit(id);
            state('Save');
        } else {
            controller.save();
            state('Edit');
        }

    });
```

...but this does not work.

This example is just an example; I know there are many ways to do what it's trying to do without saving the selector and the function to a variable. Nonetheless, the question still stands: is it possible to do this faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just

```
$('#' + id + ' .edit').on('click', function(){
    $(this).text(function(_, txt) {
        if (txt == 'Edit') {
            controller.edit(id);
            return 'Save';
        } else if (txt == 'Save') {
            controller.save();
            return 'Edit';
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Your particular example doesn't change the text of the button after it's been clicked. And as I'd mentioned, I know there are different ways of doing it without saving the selector and function. I want to know whether saving selector and function is at all possible.

Comment: @sg.cc - It's not really clear what you're trying to do, as the code you've posted doesn't really make any sense, but I edited  the answer to change the button text as well ?

Comment: `$(this).text(_, txt) {` doesn't make sense. I assume you meant to write `$(this).text(function (_, txt) {`

Answer (score 0):

jQuery elements are objects so why not **store directly into your Object element** the desired state:

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/qugun/1/edit?html,js,console,output)**

```
$('div#' + id + ' .edit').click(function(){
  var es = this.es ^= 1;           // Toggle/Store state
  $(this).text(es?'Save':'Edit');
  return controller[es?'edit':'save'](id);
});
```